# How Gson is filling values in private member data?

Tags: android, oop, gson

We can use gson for parsing JSON response and save our time. I have used this in numerous projects. What question came in my mind is even if we declare variable final, gson can fill that variables value.

Now this something strange and conflicting with OOP principals. How can any other thing except that class can access those private variables?

Is there any principal or concept which does this, probably as a part of Serialization or something like that ?

Also one more thing, in case of making it Parcelable we always have one parameterised constructor. At that time how Gson can create object of our class in absence of default constructor?

Comment: Does your class have a constructor that sets the properties?

Comment: Most of the times No. Also one thing, in case of making it Parcelable we always ahve constructor. at that time how Gson can create object of our class in absence of default constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Gson is using Java "Reflection" for accessing the private fields of other class.